# BFS father attribute in igraph is wrong

Tags: r, igraph

I am using the igraph package and I am uncertain whether it is a bug or not, but the $father output makes no sense sometimes. Specifically, when I rename the vertex attributes.

```
h<-make_tree(10)

#with normal vertex attributes
graph.bfs(h, root="1", neimode='out', order=TRUE, father=TRUE,unreachable=FALSE) #father output seems correct
plot(h,layout=layout_as_tree)

#with renamed vertex attributes
set.seed(1)
h<-set.vertex.attribute(h, "name", value=sample(1:10,10))
plot(h,layout=layout_as_tree)
graph.bfs(h, root="3", neimode='out', order=TRUE, father=TRUE,unreachable=FALSE)  #father output seems wrong
```

I obtain the output as below

```
#with normal vertex attributes
$order
+ 10/10 vertices, from ff55a96:
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$rank
NULL

$father
+ 10/10 vertices, from ff55a96:
 [1] NA  1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  5

#with renamed vertex attributes
$order
+ 10/10 vertices, named, from 170f7a0:
 [1] 3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6  10 1 

$rank
NULL

$father
+ 10/10 vertices, named, from 170f7a0:
 [1] 3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6  10 1
```

I do not understand why the father for the renamed vertex attributes case is wrong. For example, the first element should be NA but its not.

Can someone explain what is happening? If so how do I fix this such that my father elements reflects something similar to the first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit strange, but for some reason, the `bfs` function has a straight assignment of the vertex names to the names of the `father` vector. See the 54-55 line of code in the source code:

```
   if (father) 
      names(res$father) <- V(graph)$name
```

Clearly, this simply overwrites the names of `res$father` with the vector of names in the graph. Notice that this conditional statement requires the argument `igraph_opt("add.vertex.names")` to be true.

So we can avoid this behavior by setting the global option for adding vertex names to false.

```
> igraph_options()$add.vertex.names
[1] TRUE
> igraph_options(add.vertex.names=F)
> igraph_options()$add.vertex.names
[1] FALSE
```

Now it should work:

```
h<-make_tree(10)
set.seed(1)
h<-set_vertex_attr(h, "name", value=sample(1:10,10))
bfs(h, root=1, neimode='out', order=TRUE, rank=TRUE, father=TRUE,unreachable=FALSE)
```

Output:

```
    $root
[1] 1

$neimode
[1] "out"

$order
+ 10/10 vertices, named:
 [1] 3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6  10 1 

$rank
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$father
+ 10/10 vertices, named:
 [1] <NA> 3    3    4    4    5    5    7    7    2   

$pred
NULL

$succ
NULL

$dist
NULL
```

Might be worth raising this on the `igraph` github, since this seems (at least to me) like undesirable behavior.

Comment: thank you. but try this example. there is a bug in the code. `tree<-graph_from_literal(3-+5:6,6-+2,3-+4);
obj<-graph.bfs(tree,root=3, neimode="out",father=TRUE,order=TRUE,unreachable = FALSE);
obj$order;obj$father`. Observe that the output is `obj$order =  6    2    <NA> <NA> <NA>`  and `obj$father= 3 5 6 2 4`. But I expect it to be  `obj$order =  3 5 6 4 2`  and `obj$father= NA 3 3 3 2`. Your work-around does not change this

Comment: This is because using `graph_from_literal` automatically assigns vertex names, which are stored as characters. In this example, the `root=3` argument calls the third node, which is node "6" (`V(tree)$name[3]`). Change the argument to `bfs(tree,root='3', neimode="out",father=TRUE,order=TRUE,unreachable = FALSE)`.

Comment: Strange stuff still, as the `order` results and `father` results don't match up exactly. It is indicating 6 is the father of 2 and not 4. Might be a bug.

Comment: Agreed. I' ll file a github issue. Thanks

Comment: [Linking to the github issue thread.](https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/228)